# Erro de javascript - Uncaught TypeError - Não consigo resolver

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, twitter-bootstrap

Me dá o seguinte erro: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. Ainda não consegui resolver. Já alterei as versões da jquery e nada. Procurei por erros de aspas, ponto-e-vírgula e mesmo assim ainda não consegui resolver. O erro dá nessa linha da minha função jquery: `$('#jqxTree').jqxTree({ height: '400px', hasThreeStates: true, checkboxes: true, width: '330px' });`

Esse é um código que eu peguei na net. Em uma página HTML ele funcionou, inclusive fazia parte de outro post meu que dei como encerrado pela resposta encontrada. Porem agora que estou passando para a minha view(cshtml) é que começou a dar pau. Havia 9 erros e 8 foram resolvidos, porem esse ainda não consegui resolver. Já tive outros problemas em outro lugares, com esse mesmo erro, porem dessa vez não estou conseguindo. Segue um print da página no momento do erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo a minha função jquery e o meu cshtml.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // create jqxTree
    $('#jqxTree').jqxTree({ height: '400px', hasThreeStates: true, checkboxes: true, width: '330px' });
    $('#jqxTree').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('#jqxCheckBox').jqxCheckBox({ width: '200px', height: '25px', checked: true });
    $('#jqxCheckBox').on('change', function (event) {
        var checked = event.args.checked;
        $('#jqxTree').jqxTree({ hasThreeStates: checked });
    });
    $("#jqxTree").jqxTree('selectItem', $("#home")[0]);

    $('label.tree-toggler').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(300);
    });

});
```

Meu cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Acao";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutBase.cshtml";
}

<link href="~/Content/Jqwidgets/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<h2>Tomada de Ação</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label for="cbxCodTipo">UF:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control col-md-6" name="cbxCodTipo" id="cbxCodTipo" onchange=" return MontaCidades();">
                <option value="00">Selecione um estado</option>
                <option value="AC">ACRE</option>
                <option value="AL">ALAGOAS</option>
                <option value="AP">AMAPÁ</option>
                <option value="AM">AMAZONAS</option>
                <option value="BA">BAHIA</option>
                <option value="CE">CEARÁ</option>
                <option value="DF">DISTRITO FEDERAL</option>
                <option value="ES">ESPÍRITO SANTO</option>
                <option value="GO">GOIÁS</option>
                <option value="MA">MARANHÃO</option>
                <option value="MT">MATO GROSSO</option>
                <option value="MS">MATO GROSSO DO SUL</option>
                <option value="MG">MINAS GERAIS</option>
                <option value="PA">PARÁ</option>
                <option value="PB">PARAÍBA</option>
                <option value="PR">PARANÁ</option>
                <option value="PE">PERNAMBUCO</option>
                <option value="PI">PIAUÍ</option>
                <option value="RJ">RIO DE JANEIRO</option>
                <option value="RN">RIO GRANDE DO NORTE</option>
                <option value="RS">RIO GRANDE DO SUL</option>
                <option value="RO">RONDÔNIA</option>
                <option value="RR">RORAIMA</option>
                <option value="SC">SANTA CATARINA</option>
                <option value="SP">SÃO PAULO</option>
                <option value="SE">SERGIPE</option>
                <option value="TO">TOCANTINS</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="cbxCidade">Cidade:</label>
            </div>
            <select class="form-control col-md-4" name="cbxCidade" id="cbxCidade"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label for="cbxRede">Rede:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control col-md-6" name="cbxRede" id="cbxRede"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="cbxRede">Descrição:</label>
            </div>
            <select class="form-control col-md-4" name="cbxDescricao" id="cbxDescricao"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label for="cbxProduto">Produto:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control col-md-6" name="cbxProduto" id="cbxProduto"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label for="cbxUnNegocio">Unidade Negócio:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control col-md-6" name="cbxUnNegocio" id="cbxUnNegocio"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />

<div id="content">
    <div class="listTree"></div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick=" return CadastraUsuario();">Pesquisar</button>
</div>
<br>
<div id='jqxWidget'>
<div style='float: left;'>
    <div id='jqxTree' style='visibility: hidden; float: left; margin-left: 20px;'>
        <ul>
            <li item-checked='true' item-expanded='true'>
                Solutions
                <ul>
                    <li>Education</li>
                    <li>Financial services</li>
                    <li>Government</li>
                    <li item-checked='false'>Manufacturing</li>
                    <li>
                        Solutions
                        <ul>
                            <li>Consumer photo and video</li>
                            <li>Mobile</li>
                            <li>Rich Internet applications</li>
                            <li>Technical communication</li>
                            <li>Training and eLearning</li>
                            <li>Web conferencing</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>All industries and solutions</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                Products
                <ul>
                    <li>PC products</li>
                    <li>Mobile products</li>
                    <li>All products</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                Support
                <ul>
                    <li>Support home</li>
                    <li>Customer Service</li>
                    <li>Knowledge base</li>
                    <li>Books</li>
                    <li>Training and certification</li>
                    <li>Support programs</li>
                    <li>Forums</li>
                    <li>Documentation</li>
                    <li>Updates</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                Communities
                <ul>
                    <li>Designers</li>
                    <li>Developers</li>
                    <li>Educators and students</li>
                    <li>Partners</li>
                    <li>
                        By resource
                        <ul>
                            <li>Labs</li>
                            <li>TV</li>
                            <li>Forums</li>
                            <li>Exchange</li>
                            <li>Blogs</li>
                            <li>Experience Design</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                Company
                <ul>
                    <li>About Us</li>
                    <li>Press</li>
                    <li>Investor Relations</li>
                    <li>Corporate Affairs</li>
                    <li>Careers</li>
                    <li>Showcase</li>
                    <li>Events</li>
                    <li>Contact Us</li>
                    <li>Become an affiliate</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div style='margin-left: 60px; float: left;'>
        <div style='margin-top: 10px;'>
            <input id='jqxCheckBox' type="hidden">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="txtObs">Observação:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <textarea id="txtObs" style="width: 450px;"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div id="content">
        <div class="listTree"></div>
        <button class="btn btn-success" ">Gravar</button>
        @Html.ActionLink("Voltar", "Index", "Home", new { }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
    </div>

    @*<script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>*@
    <script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Acao/Acao.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Util.js"></script>



    <script src="~/Scripts/Jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Jqwidgets/jqxpanel.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Jqwidgets/jqxtree.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Coloquei um `$` dentro da function e funcionou, mas não sei se seria o correto.

Ficou assim minha function:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) { ... });
```

Comment: Esse `$` que você passou garante que dentro dessa função `$` se refira ao jQuery. No momento em que roda o `ready`, `$` fora da função foi provavelmente redefinido para outra coisa (outra biblioteca foi carregada, ou outra versão do jQuery).